# Constructor with string (using char array) parameter

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Just to make everyone aware. I **have to use char array** for strings, this is homework and has to be done that way. Also the classes are made on purporse.

I'm supposed to read a fish' name via my Fish class, which is a subclass of Animal class. If the input length is more than 0, then I'll run the constructor with the char array parameter and update the "fishname" inside Fish class. If not, I'll run the constructor without parameter (Fish() constructor).

**My questions:**

1. Right now it gives me the option to write in an input, I do that - it crashes. It is the Fish object causing it, but don't know why. How come?
2. How would I transport the data that I'll get into "fishname" in the Fish data, over to "name" in the Animal class?

So this is what I have made so far, but it only crashes after input.
     #include 
using namespace std;

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
    char* name;

public:
    Animal() { strcpy(name, ""); }          // Constructors that set name to nothing
    void writeName() { cout << name; }      // Function to read an animal's name
};

class Fish : public Animal {
private: 
    char* fishname;

public:
    Fish() {}
    Fish(const char* name) { strcpy(fishname, name); } 

};

int main() {

    char fishname[20];
    cout << "Read fish's name: "; cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(fishname, 20);

    if(strlen(fishname) > 0) Fish f1(fishname);
    else Fish f1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation of `strcpy` say about the destination string?

Comment: Using a debugger will give you more information about where your program is crashing.  Talk with the instructor and have the instructor teach the class how to use a debugger.

Comment: In addition to @StoryTeller comment, prefer to use `strncpy` (notice the 'n'`) so you don't overflow the destination character array.

Comment: Also, get in the habit of using `{` and `}` with your `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: BTW, the variables declare in your `if` statement will disappear after the `if` or `else` is executed.  Read a good C++ book about scope and local variables.

Comment: Hm probably a good idea, but I have to use functions and stuff that we have learnt through the course, and that isn't one of them :/ I tried the debugger myself, but it is just giving me an exception error with "access violation writing location". And about the fish objects being local, they are supposed to. Will be removed once they have entered all the info. It'll just quickly be displayed, and it'll be deleted.

Comment: would it be ok if you explain your teacher that instead of using a naked char array you are using a char array that is kind of hidden inside a data structure that provides a super nice interface that allows you to do the same you can do with a char array and more, in an easier to read and less error prone fashion? Imho it would be worth a try. (and just in case it isnt obvious, yes I am talking about `std::string`)

Comment: Also, read up on pointers.  Pointers need to point to things before you can use them.  You don't allocate any memory for your `fishname` in your `Fish` class.  Your pointer is pointing to random or unknown area when you declare it.

Comment: The pointer `fishname` is not initialized. You must allocate memory before you can use it.

Comment: user463035818, yes we'll be learning string eventually - but apparently we have to learn everything the "hard way". About pointers, haven't learnt that yet.

Comment: The "hard way", this is ridiculous. Here is a link for your teacher: [CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: @MemyselfandI -- *but apparently we have to learn everything the "hard way"* -- All this does is lead students to turn to Java or Python, and drop C++.

Comment: you need to know the "hard way" to appreciate and understand what `std::string` does for you, imho the problem is that just too often that "hard way" is presented to students as if it was proper c++ which it definitely isnt. I wish you enough endurance to stay till you will see the "not hard at all way" and enough flexibility to get rid of bad habits that you are forced to train until then.

Comment: You call that the hard way? Why, when I was young, we programmed paper tape in binary using our belt buckles, AND WE LIKED IT!

Comment: @user463035818 There's nothing wrong learning the hard way, but it is the order of learning, which matters. First learn the C++ way, then there's still plenty of time to learn the hard way - *and appreciate what C++ offers*.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I guess you are right. I have too little experience with teaching to know what would be the best way, but enough experience with learning. I thought for long time that c++ really is c with classes because in courses c++ was always used to introduce OO (I hate OO btw). Imho the biggest obstacle is that once you think you mastered the "high art" of passing 2D arrays as pointers and all that, you dont want to give that up so easily. I had painful years full of segfaults until I decided to forget all the crap and to learn c++ from scratch. Since that day I really love the language :)

Answer (score 0):

About the best you can do, short of implementing a lot of the functionality of std::string is to use a fixed size char array. This is *not* generally a good practice. I would not usually do this, but I will take pity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std; // NEVER write this in a header file. Just saying.

class Animal {

public:
    static const int max_name = 128;
    Animal() { 
        name[0] = 0;
    }        
    void writeName() { cout << name; }      // Function to read an animal's name
private:
    char name[max_name];

};

class Fish : public Animal {
private:
    char fishname[Animal::max_name];

public:
    Fish() {
        fishname[0] = 0;
    }
    Fish(const char* name) { 
        assert(strlen(name) < Animal::max_name);
        strcpy(fishname, name);
    }

};
```

Comment: If `#include <string.h>` is allowed (which it seems to be based on the code in the question) then OP is not being told to reimplement most of string, just the memory management.  Which is reasonable.  Hopefully by the time his class starts teaching what `strcpy` and `strrchr` look like on the inside, they'll be allowed to use premade memory management (`std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`) and only recreate the character processing.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Show me,  Sergeant.

Comment: Just saying if you look at [the list of `std::string` operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfxI4.png), all the ones I've highlighted exist in `string.h` or `stdio.h` so he can call those versions and not rewrite them.